# AdMob testmode show in emulator not in phone

Tags: android, admob

I qadrouple checked phone Id. Still does not work. What, besides of phone Id, is the difference betwween running on the Emulator and on the phone?

Comment: Try pasting the log. Admob says exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Had some trouble with USB-debugging, but now it works. And the error was to small size for the AdView container.

Answer (score 0):

And, as the documentation [specifies](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html#istesting):

> Then run your app in the Emulator and click on the displayed test ad, a browser should cover the whole screen. You should leave this property turned on during development in order to avoid generating false impressions. It’s ignored on devices so there’s no need to worry about leaving it in production.

So the admob test banner only shows up when running the program under the emulator.